# How to join a data frame with another one based on a condition using curly braces {}

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to join a data frame with another one based on a condition using curly braces {}.
I tried this but I got an error :

```
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.frame(
  Species = c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"),
  var = c(1,2,3),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

param <- "yes"

resultat <- iris %>% 
  
  {if (param=="no") filter(.) #do nothing
    else if (param=="yes") 
      # join here
      left_join(.,
                mydf,
                by = "Species")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue with indentation; the following works

```r
resultat <- iris %>% {
    if (param == "no") filter(.)
    else if (param == "yes") left_join(., mydf, by = "Species") }


all.equal(resultat, iris %>% left_join(mydf, by = "Species"))
# [1] TRUE
```